# Installation drive, /dev/sda or /dev/sdd?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, drive

While installing Ubuntu, I have followed the tutorial perfectly up until I begin partitioning. From here, the space I freed up appears to be on `sdd` drive, and I do not have an `sda` drive at all. Obviously I can still create the same partitions here, but for my boot loader installation would I select `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdd` or `/dev/sdc` (`sdc` appearing as my lowest lettered choice in the partitioning space)

[image: screenshot of the installer view]

Comment: I am not using an SSD. C drive is two HDDS in raid, and f/e are single drives.

Comment: so what is on sda? The system will always number them from a to z :P But what gets the a is undetermined: that is based on how quick the disks report to be ready for use.

Comment: Looking at my screen, I have a lot of things called dev/mapper/isw_cgbibhiedi of different volumes. Under that is SDC, sdc1 sdd, sdd1, Sdd5, sdd6 and nothing more

Comment: https://postimg.cc/ZCZ9Cj7v this is a picture, if it helps

Comment: For boot loader you should write on **bootable drive**. Which drive do you think it's loaded after BIOS Booting? If you create a RAID the bootloader should understand how to "operate" the RAID you installing.

Comment: I would have to agree. It sounds like the disk you are viewing isnt the one you think it is. The missing partitions (a,b, etc.) are probably assigned to volumes which already existed on the disk. If you dont need those other disks for anything during the install, i would just unplug them and use the two you are planning on using for RAID. Here is a link that explains how to format and partition the drives for use with RAID prior to installing: [Ubuntu RAID Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID)